# Using a CDN for jQuery and jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, cdn

For my Drupal 6 site, I'd like to get the latest jQuery and jQuery UI from Google CDN. Although this seems like something that many people would want to do, it seems that it isn't so easy.

The [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation](http://drupal.org/project/advagg) module seems promising, but after installing it and trying to use the Google CDN in the standard way, for example using `drupal_set_html_head()` to add the following lines in `<head>`, those files aren't available.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

How can I get the latest jQuery and jQuery UI from a CDN like Google CDN?

Comment: How are you loading this? Are you manually editing page.tpl.php for this? If there are a number of page-*.tpl.php then are you correctly adding on all files. The correct way is to use drupal_add_js('path/to/js');

Comment: @Shoaib, my understanding is that drupal_add_js in Drupal 6 is only for local javascript and does not work with external javascript, such as from a CDN.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @jeff the advagg module does enable that.

Comment: @Jeff Oh ya. You are right. I just cleared it. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeremy, any thoughts as to why what I did above didn't work?  Or can you point me to some docs for advagg that might explain more?

Comment: @jeff I have updated my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 6 ships with jQuery 1.2.3 and the jQuery Update module can push it to 1.3.2. You are trying to use a much more recent version of jQuery than Drupal 6 can handle. Drupal uses a lot of jQuery in its workings, so it isn't straightforward to put a new version on top.

Otherwise, those files are available in https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js.

Comment: They are, but I can't get them to work in Drupal.  I'm able to use them on non-Drupal sites,e.g., Google app engine sites.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the above with jQuery 1.3.2 and jQueryUI 1.7.3 (which other people have got working without CDN) and report back how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lastest version of JQuery and JQuery UI in Drupal 6 by using jQuery.noConflict().  This will allow you to have both multiple versions of the library for specific needs.

See the Drupal documentation here:

[Using Newer Versions of jQuery with Drupal 6](http://drupal.org/node/1058168)